# Prism: How to load Module only if dll exists

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am building a WPF Application using Prism and Unity.

I have a module that should not be used by everyone, so I want to build it that the program starts without the module dll, but when I copy the module dll to the output folder and restart the program, the module should be loaded.

I am using a XamlModuleCatalog:

```
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Modularity="clr-namespace:Prism.Modularity;assembly=Prism.Wpf">

    <Modularity:ModuleInfo 
                Ref="file://TrayManager.UI.dll"
                ModuleName="UIModule" 
                ModuleType="TrayManager.UI.UIModule, TrayManager.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo 
                Ref="file://TrayManager.PasswordEncryption.dll"
                InitializationMode="OnDemand"
                ModuleName="PasswordEncryptionModule" 
                ModuleType="TrayManager.PasswordEncryption.PasswordEncryptionModule, TrayManager.PasswordEncryption, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />

</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

When I set the InitializationMode of my PasswordEncryptionModule to 'OnDemand', it will never be loaded, but the program starts.

When I set the InitializationMode to 'WhenAvailable' the program only starts if the dll is in the output folder.

In my App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            _logger.Debug("Shell created");
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {

        }

        protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog() {

            return new XamlModuleCatalog(new Uri("/TrayManager;component/ModuleCatalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could use the `DirectoryModuleCatalog`, perhaps, it loads the modules it finds at runtime.

Comment: Made an answer of the comment to increase visibility if someone comes here from google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DirectoryModuleCatalog` loads all the modules it finds in a given folder which makes it a good fit if the modules are deployed independent of the application or vary over time.